# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'johnnyappleseed'@'localhost' (using password: YES) on Mac

Tags: mysql, macos

Each time I run this command in the terminal:

`$ mysql -u johnnyappleseed -p`

And then I enter the password, I receive this error message:

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'johnnyappleseed'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Any ideas why I am receiving this error message and what does it mean?

Comment: No, I'm not sure what they mean by anonymous user

Comment: Where did the user named "johnnyappleseed" come from? What privileges were granted to it?

Comment: Is this same error occurred while login with the same credentials in superuser mode?